# Match from list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am still learning python, trying things.

I have code that search for word 'Lorem' in text and replace with random word from list. This is working.

What I wanna do now is how to check if any word from list (words = ['and', 'a', 'is', 'the']) is in text  and replace with another word from another list (t = ['TEXT', 'REPLACE', 'WORD']).

I wanna replace 'Lorem' with variable or loop thru list or open txt file with words to check.

res = re.sub('Lorem', lambda x: random.choice(t), text)

If possible if someone can show me all 3 options:

-loop through list
-variable
-open file with words inside

Or maybe there is other, better way?

Thanks!

---

here is full code

---

```
import re
import random

t = ['TEXT', 'REPLACE', 'WORD']

text = '''Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum'''

words = ['and', 'a', 'is', 'the']

res = re.sub('Lorem', lambda x: random.choice(t), text)

print(res)
```

Comment: How does `words` correspond to `t`? Are we to assume you just randomly replace with one of the words from `t`? If not, I would suggest you create a dictionary mapping which words ought to be replaced with certain other words.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will replace Any word in `text` that is also in `words` with a random word from `replacement`.

```
import random
replacement = ['TEXT', 'REPLACE', 'WORD', 'LIST']

text = '''Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum'''
#  with open('ipsum.txt') as tf: text = tf.read(None)

words = ['and', 'a', 'is', 'the']

text_words = text.split()

for ti, tw in enumerate(text_words):
    if tw in words:
        text_words[ti] = random.choice(replacement)

print(' '.join(text_words))

#  Possible output:
#  Lorem Ipsum WORD simply dummy text of LIST printing REPLACE typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been REPLACE industry's standard dummy text ever since TEXT 1500s, when an unknown printer took WORD galley of type LIST scrambled it to make WORD type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also TEXT leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in WORD 1960s with REPLACE release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, REPLACE more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum
```

If you want to take from `replacement` at the same index as in `words`, you can use this loop:

```
for ti, tw in enumerate(text_words):
    try:
        wi = words.index(tw)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    else:
        text_words[ti] = replacement[wi]

print(' '.join(text_words))

#  Result:
#  Lorem Ipsum WORD simply dummy text of LIST printing TEXT typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been LIST industry's standard dummy text ever
```

Comment: @sLOVEnia, if it solves your question please mark as solution. thx!